# powershell import csv, delete rows+change header row and export back to csv

Tags: csv, powershell

I have a csv of the below form:

[original csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dutux.jpg)

What I would like to achieve is to import the csv, delete all rows until the second headers row and export it back to csv with the new headers this time.

I've written the below, but doesn't seem to work:

```
$csvimport = get-content C:\Win12simpleExpComp.csv
$firstline = "Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4"
$csvpre = $csvimport.Where({ $_ -like "$firstline" },'SkipUntil');
$csvpre | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\export.csv
```

What I get in the exported csv is like below:

```
PSPath,"PSParentPath","PSChildName","PSDrive","PSProvider","ReadCount","Length"
C:\Win12simpleExpComp.csv,"C:\","Win12simpleExpComp.csv","C","Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem","39","205"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$csvpre | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation C:\export.csv
```

Do:

```
$csvpre | Out-File C:\export.csv
```